# Out of memory on ffmpeg when converting to H265

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, out-of-memory, h.264, h.265

I've a bunch of video files, mostly H264. To save storage, I wrote a batch script, that converts all of them to H265 using ffmpeg. Problem: Some files cause ffmpeg to use ALL my memory (24 GB). Then it crashes (cause it try to allocate even more RAM), which stops the converting process.

I think that these files are corrupt in some kind. Because with other files, it works well with low memory consumption. Now I want to reject those broken ones, so that unattended converting is possible.

*How is it possible to detect such corruption? Can ffmpeg do this, or is a third party tool required?*

#### My ffmpeg call

```
set crf=20
set codec=265

ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "!fullSourcePath!" -c:v libx%codec% -crf %crf% "%targetPath%\!targetFileName!"
```

#### mkvalidator can't help

[mkvalidator](https://matroska.org/downloads/mkvalidator.html) says that a corrupt file is valid:

```
mkvalidator.exe "V:\Filme\_LegacyFormat\22 Jump Street.mkv"
........................................................................................................................
WRN0D0: There are 5306 bytes of void data..

mkvalidator 0.5.0: the file appears to be valid
        file created with libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1 / mkvmerge v6.9.1 ('Blue Panther') 64bit built on Apr 18 2014 18:23:38
```

#### eac3to331 can't help, too

I found the tool [eac3to331](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=eac3to&addon=chrome&addonversion=2.0.3), which has a `check` flag. But it gave me no errors, although the tested file seems corrupt (cause my PC to crash after several minutes running ffmpeg)

```
eac3to.exe -check "V:\Filme\_LegacyFormat\22 Jump Street.mkv"
MKV, 1 video track, 2 audio tracks, 1 subtitle track, 1:51:57, 24p /1.001
1: h264/AVC, English, 1920x808 24p /1.001 (240:101)
2: DTS, German, 5.1 channels, 1509kbps, 48kHz
3: DTS, English, 5.1 channels, 1509kbps, 48kHz
4: Subtitle (SRT), German
v01 Extracting video track number 1...
a02 Extracting audio track number 2...
a03 Extracting audio track number 3...
s04 Extracting subtitle track number 4...
Video track 1 contains 161039 frames.
eac3to processing took 1 minute, 26 seconds.
Done.
```

Comment: Hard to say without taking a look at your "corrupt" files. Can you share a sample file? It could be giant GOPs some long-term reference frame gone bad.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann Hmm I don't think that this is possible on a platform like SO which is public only, cause it's copyrighted material... Posting it here would surely result in DCMA issues.

Comment: Why do you think these files are corrupted? Are you able to play them? It may be a bug in ffmpeg as well. At least, the ffmpeg shoult report problem if the video is corrupted and not take so much memory.

Comment: ffmpeg is a constant moving target, if you are on linux, compile it from source using the git-master to see if the problem still persist. Without a sample-file it is almost impossible to help you I'm afraid. As other have asked, can you play the *corrupt* files using e.g. `ffplay` or `vlc`?